# Google Sheets: Conditional Formatting - Individual Rows

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

**This question was posted 4/1/21 (d/m/yy).**

In Google Sheets, I have a table of all my tests, like below:

| Subject | Test | Date (d/m/yy) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **C3** - Biology | 1 | 1/1/21 |
| **C4** - Chemistry | 2 | 3/1/21 |
| **C5** - Music | 3 | 4/1/21 |
| **C6** - Physics | 4 | 6/1/21 |

In Column D, I have the formula `=TODAY()`, which gets today's current date.

In Column E, I have the formula `=IFS(C3=D3,"Today",C3<D3,"Past",C3>D3,"Future")`, which prints "Today" if the test is today, "Past" if it has passed, and "Future" if it is yet to happen.
*In each row, the `C3` and `D3` values change to the row number.*

I have these conditional formatting rules in `C3`:

- `=E3="Today"` **RANGE: C3**
- `=E3="Past"` **RANGE: C3**
- `=E3="Future"` **RANGE: C3**

[image: Conditional formatting]

However, when I "drag" this cell to copy conditional formatting rules to `C4`, this happens:

- `=E3="Today"` **RANGE: C3:C4**
- `=E3="Past"` **RANGE: C3:C4**
- `=E3="Future"` **RANGE: C3:C4**

I have tried putting these in the column of C, but it comes up as an error:

- `=E$="Today"`
- `=E$="Past"`
- `=E$="Future"`

#### TL DR: How can I create conditional formatting for a row that changes according to its' row number?

Comment: see I column CF: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11vsBPepzYGiGAI8k5sWVVbfqh87--tMjmGsj6FNPkBc/edit#gid=1330538035

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=E3="Today"
```

on range **C3:C**

if you want to paint the whole row use:

```
=$E3="Today"
```

on range **A3:C**